# Maven error: cannot access OpenListResourceBundle when building with annotation processor library

Tags: java, android, maven

Working on a new project I've run into a major roadblock that has brought my progress to a crawl.  A little about my project... it is an annotation processing tool much like [AndroidAnnotations](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) that scans for annotations and builds up Android specific code accordingly.

The error seems to be related to the Java6 annotation processing, Android API and Maven, and only appears when I have an instance of a type from the Android API declared in a processed class.  Here's the error I am running into when including my library:

```
...
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /mnt/hd1/home/john/dev/robotics-project/examples/simple/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
error: cannot access sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
error: cannot access sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
... 17 more
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
error: cannot access sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle
```

Here is the repository for my code:  https://github.com/johncarl81/robotics

To reproduce the error, replace TestController.java with the following:

```
public class TestController {

    @Inject
    private SubComponent subComponent;
    @Inject
    private Activity activity;
    public boolean validate() {
        return subComponent != null && activity != null;
    }

}
```

Then build the project from the root by running:

```
mvn clean install
```

sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle is available on the classpath, as I am running java 1.6.0_26 in an Ubuntu environment.  I have tried this on multiple ubuntu machines as well as windows with exactly the same problem.

Any help or ideas on what to try is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question I went back to the drawing board and looked at everything that was happening during the annotation processing phase.  Turns out that the android.app.Activity class and all of its related classes (parameter types, etc) were being analyzed by my library.  This seems to have caused the annotation processor to trigger some sort of review on those classes, which seems to include the rt.jar class mentioned.  This then caused the error, because that class could not be accessed by the compiler.

The solution was to trim the analysis of irrelevant classes during the annotation processing phase.

Hope that helps anyone that may come across this problem in the future (although probably unlikely).